# Curvature of Weyl-rescaled metric from curvature of original metric

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, ads-cft, branes

I'm trying to go from the low-energy effective action in the string-frame to the corresponding action in the Einstein frame. The action in the string frame has the form

$$S = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^7 l_s^8}\int d^{10}x \sqrt{-\gamma}\left[e^{-2\Phi}(R[\gamma_{\mu\nu}] + 4(\nabla\Phi)^2) - \frac{1}{2}\left|F_{p+2}\right|^2\right]$$

Here $\gamma_{\mu\nu}$ is the string-frame metric, and $R[\gamma_{\mu\nu}]$ is the usual Einstein curvature for this metric, which appears in the first (dilaton corrected) Einstein-Hilbert like term in the action.

The process is two fold:

1. Introduce a field $\phi$ for fluctuations $e^{\Phi} = g_s e^{\phi}$ ($\Phi$ in this language is the dilaton).
2. Weyl rescale the metric $g_{\mu\nu} = e^{-\phi/2}\gamma_{\mu\nu}$.

The second step ought to yield the following relationship between the scalar curvatures:

$$R[\gamma_{\mu\nu}] = e^{-\phi/2}\left[R[g_{\mu\nu}] - \frac{9}{2}\nabla^2\phi - \frac{9}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2\right]$$

So my problem right now is to cleanly derive this curvature relationship, which is really a GR problem. One way to go about it is to start from the Christoffel symbols for $g$ and show that they are equal to the Christoffel symbols for $\gamma$ plus $\phi$-dependent correction terms, then go the Riemann curvature tensor, and then finally to the Ricci tensor, in the usual canonical way.

However, I am hoping there's a faster way to to do this (vielbeins maybe? I can't think of a direct application) because the algebra in this standard procedure is quite tedious.

The general problem has a simple statement: **how do you relate the curvature of a Weyl rescaled metric to its original curvature?**

Comment: How did you get that equation in the first place?

Comment: [1] R.M. Wald, *General Relativity* (1984), Appendix D. [2] S. Carroll, *Spacetime and Geometry* (2003), Appendix G. [3] A. Zee, *Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell* (2013), p. 353.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Omega^2=\exp\phi/2$ so that $\gamma=\Omega^2 g$. Then we have the standard formula 
$$R_\gamma=\Omega^{-2}\big(R_g-2(n-1)\Delta\ln\Omega-(n-2)(n-1)[\nabla\ln\Omega]^2\big)$$
This is proven in any number of General Relativity texts, but the one in R.M. Wald, *General Relativity* (1984), is particularly easy to follow and is proved in the form shown here. From above we get $\Omega=\exp\phi/4$ so that $\ln\Omega=\phi/4$. Furthermore, we have $n=10$ so that the coefficients of the last two terms are $2\cdot 9$ and $8\cdot 9$. From the $\ln\Omega$s we get factors of $1/4$ and $1/4^2$ on the second and third terms, respectively. Thus we have $9/2$ in front of those terms. Putting it all together, we obtain
$$R_\gamma=\exp(-\phi/2)\big(R_g-\tfrac{9}{2}\Delta\phi-\tfrac{9}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2\big)$$ 
as was to be shown.